# Why isn't there a djvu2text?

Tags: conversion, djvu, text

This has been bothering me for a while.

.djvu files are often searchable, in my experience. So somewhere in there, all the text is just one big string, right? But there's no djvu2text program. And trying to select text in a djvu reader is a bit nightmarish, I find.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes, there is.** Though its name is **`djvutxt`**, not `djvu2text`.

It is part of:

- the `djvu` package on Gentoo.
- the `djvulibre-bin` package on Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: It is in `djvulibre-bin` package in Debian and in Ubuntu.